# MissingPluginException for awaitCameras with the camera plugin

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to use the camera plugin to get a preview of the camera. However, I just keep getting an error saying a method that is needed to do so is unavailable. The code I am using at the minute is very basic and I can't find anything that would be causing the issue. I've already added the plugin to my pubspec and set the minSdkVersion to 21, from what I can find these are the only prerequisites for using the plugin.

My code is as follows -

```
class LiveViewFragmentState extends State<LiveViewFragment> {
  bool _loading = true;
  bool _mountedSuccessfully = false;
  late CameraController _cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCamera();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCamera() async {
    try {
      List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
      _cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
      _cameraController.initialize().then((_) =>
      {

        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _loading = false;
            _mountedSuccessfully = mounted;
          })
        }
      });
    } on CameraException catch(_) {
        setState(() {
          _loading = false;
          _mountedSuccessfully = false;
        });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_loading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      if (_mountedSuccessfully) {
        return CameraPreview(_cameraController);
      } else {
        return Text("Could not load camera.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the stack trace I get is as follows -

```
E/flutter ( 9470): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method availableCameras on channel plugins.flutter.io/camera)
E/flutter ( 9470): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 9470): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9470): #1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:344:35)
E/flutter ( 9470): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9470): #2      MethodChannelCamera.availableCameras (package:camera_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_camera.dart:62:52)
E/flutter ( 9470): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9470): #3      LiveViewFragmentState._loadCamera (package:color/ui/fragments/live_view_fragment.dart:27:41)
E/flutter ( 9470): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9470):
```

Comment: Did you try a full rebuild the app again after adding the plugin.

Comment: @sajithlakmal I assumed I already had since I told the app not to hot restart, but apparently not. A full restart and rebuild fixed it, thanks <3.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Sajith, a full rebuild solved the issue.

Comment: Solved it for me as well.